# Custom search box using your own <input type="text">

Tags: javascript, datatables

As you can see in [this example](http://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/zero_configuration.html) jQuery DataTables has a search box function.

I want to create customized search box design. Is it possible to create your own using the code below outside the DataTables?

```
<input type="text" id="search" name="search">
```

Comment: So what is the question

Comment: @SunilPachlangia as you can see the datables has a search box. how can I create my own search box using <input type> not javascript.

Comment: Why can't you customise the existing datatables search box?

Comment: I dont know how. the search box in on the external .js file

Answer (score 1):

Please see [Search API example](http://datatables.net/examples/api/regex.html) and how **Global search** is implemented.

For example, you can use the code below where `search` is ID of your search box:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable();

    $('#search').on( 'keyup click', function () {
       $('#example').DataTable().search(
           $('#search').val()
       ).draw();
    } );     
} );
```